# How can i find a stationary point despite a contradiction in its first derivative?

Tags: calculus, curves

For an equation $y = (x-3)^3 + 2x$, the first derivative is $\frac{dy}{dx} = 3(x-3)^2 + 2$. When the first derivative is 0, we have $(x-3)^2 = \frac{-2}{3}$ which is a contradiction, assuming there are only real roots. Yet for this equation, there seems to be a stationary point according to the graphic calculator that looks like this:

[image]

Does this mean there are no stationary points at all? If so, how can I sketch the curve without knowing where to "curve" in the graph?

Comment: For $x \simeq 3$ you don't have a stationary point. It seems to be an inflection point, i.e. a point where the second derivative changes sign

Comment: Isn't $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ a necessary but insufficient condition for there to be an inflection point?

Comment: Just as you can have the first derivative change sign at a point that’s not a zero of the function, the second derivative can change sign at points at which the first derivative is non-zero.

Comment: y is the position of a car.... x is time.... The car slowed down gradually to a minimum positive speed at time x=3, then  accelerated.

Comment: @amd That is an excellent explanation that sums up where my thinking had gone wrong, which was to assume dy/dx must be zero for an inflection point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$f'(x)=3(x-3)^2+2\geq 2$$ for all real $x$ thus your function is strictly monotonously increasing
and $$f''(x)=6(x-3)=0$$ if $x=3$ and $f''(x)=6>0$ so we have an inflection Point for $x=3,f(3)$

Comment: Actually I checked the second derivative and if I let it to be equal to 0, then x = 3 which can indicate the point of inflection. However, I'm not sure why dy/dx = 0 is a contradiction at all points.

Comment: why are you not sure? $$3(x-3)^2\geq 0$$ for all real $x$ and $$3(x-3)^2+2\geq 2>0$$

Comment: To rephrase my question, I mean why is it possible that at a point of inflection, dy/dx = 0? Is dy/dx = 0 a necessary condition for a point of inflection? I understand that if a function is monotonously increasing, dy/dx >= 0 at all points. Question is why could it not be = 0 ?

Comment: $f''(x=3) = 0$...